# Why does `sudo cat /proc/self/attr/current` return "Invalid argument"?

Tags: debian, proc, container, apparmor

I have read that the current AppArmor profile should be listed in the `/proc/self/attr/current` file, and that if it's empty the current profile is "unconfined".

But why does `cat` return "Invalid argument", when attempting to read these files? Indeed, the output of `ls -la` shows that it's a regular file?

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:/$ ls -la /proc/self/attr/current 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 parallels parallels 0 Mar  1 15:51 /proc/self/attr/current
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:/$ sudo cat /proc/self/attr/current 
cat: /proc/self/attr/current: Invalid argument
```

In particular, I've attempted to read `/proc/self/attr/current` in a Docker container, which should make use of AppArmor by default, but same error message appears?

**off-topic**: where can I find `man` documentation of the different files under `/proc/`?

Comment: Re your secondary question: [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: Even tho they look like regular files, anything in `/proc` isn't. I don't know the exact answer to your question but I would suspect that `/proc/self` is for the *shell process* and not for the `sudo` process. Does `sudo bash -c "cat /proc/self/attr/current"` work?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, thank you - unfortunately, I get same result with your command.

Comment: @StephenKitt, thank you. Are there `man` pages for all filesystem types, e.g. `nsfs`? I tried to lookup `man 5 ns`, but no result.

Comment: @Aaron `/proc/self/...` refers to whichever process opened the file; in this case, `ls` and `cat`. It would only be the shell if the shell opened it, *e.g.* for a redirection (so `cat /proc/self/...` doesn’t give the same result as `cat < /proc/self/...`).

Comment: File systems are supposed to have manpages, but they don’t all have manpages :-(.

Comment: And the `ns` entries aren’t part of a separate file system, they’re handled by the `proc` file system, and are briefly described in the corresponding manpage, with a link to [`man 7 namespaces`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html).

Comment: @StephenKitt - thanks for the clarification. I’ve seen several answers referring to a `nsfs` filesystem.

Comment: Yes, the implementation of `/proc/.../ns` lives in `fs/nsfs.c` which is a separate file system, technically, but that’s not apparent to the user (unless it fails to initialise).

Answer (score 1):

Usually AppArmor or SELinux use `/proc/[pid]/attr/current` to provides current security attributes for the process.
When it can't be read, usually AppArmor nor SELinux is enabled.